# PHP going back and keeping arguments

Tags: php, url, header

I have used this page http://www.binarytides.com/blog/php-redirect-go-back-to-previous-page/
to go back

but from

```
http://page.co/test.php?item=26
```

I post something to post.php and then call the php Go back function but I go back to

```
http://page.co/test.php
```

losing the argument path, any idea?

Comment: You can try to store the "item" GET variable in a SESSION variable and then in the post.php recall the SESSION variable to redirect to the proper page ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Your form fill in the query string to the action attribute, like this:

```
<form action="?item=26" name="myform">
...
</form>
```

and after the submission Your HTTP_REFERER will contain this query string so redirect to it will be successfull...

EDIT: If the form is on the page post.php, it is enough to use `action="?item=26"` - of course You can and should use PHP to write down the number/ID of item from whenever it may come...

Lets say Your item ID is stored in the variable $item_id - then Your action will look like this: `action="?item=<?php echo $item_id; ?>"`.

Comment: I come to test.php?item=26 using a form action="test.php" and other inputs whose item

Comment: well if you use post.php as the action then you should write action="post.php?item=26", of course you can use php to generate the number for you for each different page ...

Answer (score 0):

You should use sessions for stuff like this. Set a session when posting the data and you're set.